# making sound resembling Dead Space upgrade sound

Tags: sound-effects, sound-design

I am looking for a sound that is similar to the sound at 1:11 and 1:14 in

I have tried playing around electricity and sci fi sounds from Freesound in Audacity, but I couldn't reproduce the sound to be similar to the sound I want.

What are the bases of this sound? This sound does not exist in real life, does it? And what are the filters I need to reproduce this sound?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
This part is to address the sound "Peeeshuiiitt" associated with the pop-up windows that appear twice in the segment at 1:11 - 1:14.

This sounds like a pneumatic door opening or closing, as in a quick change of air pressure.
If you can record such a door in the field then take it into Audacity and I think you might want to speed it up (not raise the pitch but shorten the duration), add some Hall reverb to taste you will get close.

Here is a sight that will sell downloads of something close, check out the pneumatic doors...

http://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/1/pneumatic.html

======================== original answer but regarding background ambiance ===========

I am assuming you are referring to the back ground sounds at 1:11 - 1:14 while buttons are pushed in the foreground of the soundscape. This reminds me of the sounds recorded by NASA on Voyager I & II as found here:

Notably at the 1:00 to 2:00 mark.

I think if you were to record a very large bell (bass pitch) being struck or a gong, then edit out the hit or attack until you just here the ringing, you might need to drop it one to 2 octaves until it sounds hollow, then add a ton of Hall reverb. You might need to loop it too.

Another approach would be to go to a very large tunnel that only air is passing through, record the sound very carefully not to get wind directly on the mic. Then take this sound and use filters and reverb to boost the hollowness.

Yet another approach similar to the last one is to record the end of a very large tube, perhaps even a garden hose. Stretch it out, 20 - 40 feet, be sure not to get any direct wind on the mic. First put your ear up to the hose to be sure you hearing the air pass through it.

This is not far away from the old 'hear' the ocean when you put a large sea shell up to your ear. So you might even try that, record a sea shell as it passes air over its opening.

UPDATE [append]:
It occurred to me that yet another way to get this sound would be like rubbing your wet finger on the rim of wine glass as described here:

http://recipes.howstuffworks.com/food-facts/question603.htm

However, this tone is likely too high in pitch for your purposes, so taking the same idea but using perhaps a rubber mallet and rubbing the edge of huge glass bowl may get it to sing like the wine glass but much lower in pitch. Record this, then edit out the start and stop points of the rubbing so you only have the 'singing glass' part, experiment with lowering this 1 or more octaves, also add Hall reverb to taste, and possibly some filtering.

Is the sound in your example something you might experience in real life? I suspect that if you can imagine any sound you can find some thing in real life that comes close. In this case the basis of the sound appears to be a breathy like white noise through a formant filter or formant filters, or air pushing through a tube not unlike listening to tunnel hum or the ambient sounds of a long tunnel sans traffic or trains, only air. The acoustics of a tunnel produce standing waves and the length and diameter determine a resonance that when air passes though it creates some kind of tone or tones not unlike what your example touches on.

Comment: Actually I am referring to the Peeeshuiiitt sound that is played twice in that interval, not the background sound. See the light that shined up at the same time as the sound got played? That sound is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you talking about the sound associated with the pop up window?

Comment: Check out the update.